# Ports and DOM rendering

Tags: dom, codemirror, elm, elm-port

Try to use CodeMirror in my Elm app.

I bind a textarea from `update` function like that:

```
( ..., runCodemirror textAreaId)
```

Where `runCodemirror` is a port:

```
port runCodemirror : String -> Cmd msg
```

Problem is that event `ports.runCodemirror` fires before a textarea appears in DOM.

I try to solve that with `setTimeout`:

```
app.ports.runCodemirror.subscribe(
  function (textAreaId) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById(textAreaId));
      },
      100
    );
  }
);
```

but it's ugly. 100ms is too slow, I see a blinking.

Other options I have: to bind CodeMirror with invisible textarea or MutationObserver API.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use DOM [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor changes in the DOM and create the JS objects when those events fire, that way you don't need to use ports at all.

[ArriveJS](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) provides a nice wrapper around this functionality so you could do something like:

```
document.arrive(".code-mirror", function() {
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this)
})
```

You can take this further by adding `data-` attributes to the element in `Elm` and reading them on the JS side:

```
document.arrive(".code-mirror", function() {
  const lineNumbers = this.getAttribute('data-line-numbers') 
  CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, {
    lineNumbers: lineNumbers
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to abusing json decoders, you can use them to run code when an element first appears in the DOM.  I wrote about this approach here: https://medium.com/@prozacchiwawa/the-i-m-stupid-elm-language-nugget-7-8d3efd525e3e#.3hatcdfl3 .  Otherwise, MutationObserver is the way to go.